# App Store bundle invalid error when uploading build

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, cfbundleidentifier

I have just transferred an app that is on the App Store to another account.  I am now trying to upload additional builds from Xcode to the new account.  I have an error when trying to upload:

> ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key
>   CFBundleShortVersionString [0] in the Info.plist file must contain a
>   higher version than that of the previously approved version [0].
>   Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"

Under my builds in iTunes connect I have several builds in version 0 and one build in version 1 which is the version now on the store.  Can I not continue to upload builds with version 0?  Or do I have to now upload builds with version 1 or later?

And is there a best practice for assigning version and build numbers?  The new build I want to upload is just for TestFlight testing and will not be released to the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two numbers that are important:

[image]

**Version = `Bundle versions string, short`** This needs to increase with every version and does not reset. So if you have version `0` and version `1` on the store, the next one needs to be bigger than those. (Could be 1.1, 2, 3, 30, etc.) Important: This is NOT the version customers see on the App Store. This can get changed in App Store Connect.

**Build = `Bundle version`** This needs to increase for one version, meaning al builds for one version. If you are on a new version, you might start again. (Version 1 can have builds 1, 2, 3, 4. Version 2 can have builds 1, 2, 3, 4 again.)

Some examples to help clarify:
[image]